# Catch the SQL connection error for wrong username and password in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a simple springboot application which connects with MySQL, MySQL credentials are stored in application.properties .

In case if the database username/password is not correct I want to LOG this error.

so I made a try-catch in my main class

```
 try
    {
        SpringApplication.run( DashboardUtilServerApplication.class, args );
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        if(ex.getCause() instanceof HibernateException)
        {
        //Line 11
      }
```

Code is coming on line 11, But how can I sure that this exception is because of wrong DB credentials, Is there some specific exception for wrong DB credentials.

I just want to show this to the user that Database credentials are not correct. IF in application.properties the username/password for DB are not correct.

Comment: you can use getMessage method  of SQLException, it will give something like 'invalid username/password'

Comment: Create @ Configuration class for mysql connection,  and define Datasource @ Bean, catch the exception. "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user"

Comment: Generic catch clauses like the one you use as well as the introspection later on are a recipe for disaster. Before attempting to do what you want to achieve, the best question is why you want to inform the end user of your application that the database credentials are wrong? What is the use case for a feature like that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a specific exception which you can check for to determine this. You can, however, check the exception message to determine whether it was an invalid credentials issue by checking to see if the message contains 'access denied', or whatever the exact message is.